# Assign the same value if the condition is not met

Tags: if-statement, vhdl

I assume that if a certain condition is met, then `A = Y`, but if it is not met `A` takes the previous value of `A`. But I have not achieved this.

```
seleccion: process (A, x1,x2,Y)
  variable sel : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
begin 
  sel :=    (x1 & x2);
  if sel="xx" then
    A<=Y;
  else
    A<=A;
  end if;
end process seleccion;
```

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Your code seems OK. What do you mean with "previous value"? You are defining combinatoric logic (I.e. non-clocked) with your process. This way you can only assign A it's current value.

Comment: The string literal "xx" is not a value of type std_logic_vector. IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.2 Literals "The character literals corresponding to the graphic characters contained within a string literal or a bit string literal shall be visible at the place of the string literal." The element base type std_ulogic does not have a character enumeration value of 'x'. The combinatorial latch enable sel can glitch if x1 and x2 have different delay paths. *...A takes the previous value of A. But I have not achieved this.*] isn't [a specific problem or error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).